# How to make Ubuntu look more like Windows 10

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, gtk

I have had this question for a while now, and could never find a clean answer that I was satisfied with, so I am posting my findings here. I have been able to make Ubuntu 22.04 feel and act like Windows 10, with some betterment in the dash menu at the bottom of the screen.  In screenshot 2 there is a list of the extensions used, and my shell theme of choice is cloudy dark grey. (https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1297726)  I found that the Monday icon theme looks quite nice(https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1820559), as well as the ukui icon theme, but I could not find a link to a download. I had to manually move my gtk theme into the locked themes folder through terminal, and that has the issue of resetting any time I put the computer into lock or sleep mode, but it works when I enable it through Tweaks.

If anybody has any tips for the theme switching that would be much appreciated.

Desktop screenshot:

[image: desktop screenshot]

All extensions used:

[image: all extensions used]

Comment: The links to download those are right below the image in the `Files` tab on those pages.  You might want to also install `ocs-url` so that you can have it install themes and icons for you.  `sudo apt install ocs-url`

Comment: Maybe kde-look will have useful theme parts for you, like this [splash screen](https://store.kde.org/p/1865900/).